# Development environment sandboxing

Tags: c++, c, virtual-machine, lxc, linux-containers

What is the standard way to isolate development environment from system when developing in Linux? For example when I work on applications or packages which the system already use. I know could I use a virtual machine. Could Linux containers be used as well? How this isolation was performed before virtualization and containers? Was 'chroot' the tool for this? I am doing C and C++ development.

Comment: You as a normal user can't mess up the system. Being designed as multi-user, it already protects the system and other users from whatever you do as a user. If you develop with root priviles though, you have effectively disabled this protection, which is stupid. Now, even for you as a regular user, there are protections. When you compile a program or library, it is not automatically in your PATH, so use of the version from the system is still the default unless you explicitly change it. I wonder what your problem actually is...

Comment: Thanks, @UlrichEckhardt , the reason why I am asking is that I need to work on gstreamer and its plugins. The version which I am working on is 1.5.0. However on my system there is 1.4.5.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real overall Standard, but there are more or less standard approaches depending on the technology stack. For example, virtualenv is pretty much ubiquitous in python. Node has at least two popular options.

Many people use virtual machines, especially in conjunction with tools like vagrant (or docker and docker-compose for a lighter weight solution).

My understanding is that c and c++ are pretty lightweight in terms of the tooling they need. See [Is there any virtualenv like tool for c++ out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233536/is-there-any-virtualenv-like-tool-for-c-out-there). But if you include os level dependencies, like DB drivers and such, you'll probably need something to handle having different environments for different projects.

Look into vagrant along with some virtual machine technology or docker plus docker-compose.

Answer (score 1):

Red Hat makes newer GCC versions available (e.g. 5.2) via its [Developer Toolset](https://access.redhat.com/products/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/Developer/#dev-page=6) (DTS).  These newer GCC versions run along side the system toolchain so you won't muck things up as its installed in another part of the file system.  This may suffice for what you want to do, but if you also want container isolation, there's also a [Docker image version of the DTS](https://access.redhat.com/search/#/container-images) that can be used via the Red Hat container development kit ([CDK](http://developers.redhat.com/containers/adoption/)).

Answer (score 0):

Linux containers are as close as you could get to a standard isolated environment on Linux be it for development or other purposes. You can find plenty of development images, for example [these GCC Docker images](https://hub.docker.com/_/gcc/) or [create one yourself](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockerimages/) based on your favorite distribution and include all built tools and dependencies you need.

[Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) is another useful tool that helps in managing build environments, but it's most useful if you work with VMs for multiple platforms. If you only plan to use Linux containers, you probably don't need Vagrant.